# Переход из TableView в DetailView.

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Собсно есть  TableView содержащий некое количество ссылок. При нажатию на ячейку ссылка передается в следующий вью и там уже скачивается картинка. Система оказалась неудобной и надо бы ее исправить, потому что если картинка большая, то приложение "зависает". К тому же где-то вычитал, что Яблоко рекомендует, чтобы следующий вью загружался немедленно. Отсюда и вопрос - как все это дело поправить?

Немного кода:

Tableview.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];

    _urls = @[@"http://host.ru/288270_732748.jpg",
              @"http://host.ru/288270_732749.jpg",
              @"http://host.ru/288270_732750.jpg",
              @"http://host.ru/288270_732751.jpg",
              @"http://host.ru/288270_732752.jpg"
              ];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_urls count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row+1];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailView"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        DetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.downloadedimage = [_urls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

А так получаем картинку в DetailView.m:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_downloadedimage];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
self.img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_img];
```

**Обновление**

Глупо наверное, но я впихнул в DetailView вот это для загрузки картинки:

```
[self.imageView sd_setImageWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:_downloadedimage]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"123.png"]];
```

И почему-то ничего не получилось =\  Я что-то не то сделал же, да?

Answer (score 1):

Загружайте в backgroung. Открывайте сразу экран и тут же начинаете грузить в фоновом потоке, даже прогресс можно показать. Рекомендую использовать либу, коих много, я пользуюсь SDWebImage - без нареканий, обновляется, работает без сбоев, кэширует на диск и в память, есть категории для UIKit овых классов (UIImageView, UIButton и тд.), поддерживает блоки и прогресс загрузки. 
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Скажем, код в самом простом случае будет выглядеть так:

```
[self.imageView setImageWithURL: pictureURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: А разве нельзя сделать так чтобы с TаbleView уходило сразу же, а потом уже грузилась пикча с интернета?

Comment: @slake, Да, именно так и нужно сделать. Переход и уже во viewDidLoad детального представления грузим в бакграунде картинку

Comment: Эмм.. Глупо наверное, но я впихнул в DetailView вот это для загрузки картинки:  
   
[self.imageView sd_setImageWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:_downloadedimage]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"123.png"]];


И почему-то ничего не получилось =\  Я что-то не то сделал же, да?